# how to remove the same rows from the table using select query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am fetching the the data from two tables by using the following query but it is giving me duplicate records.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM animals,birds";
```

How can i remove the duplicate records in `mysql` .I tried using `DISCTINCT` keyword but that does not work and also `UNION` does not work as the number of columns are not same in both the tables.

animals_id,name in the animals table
birds_id,name in the birds table

Comment: have you tried group by?

Comment: Pls show us columns of both tables and let us know which fields contains duplicate rows

Comment: what should i group by i mean which field?

Comment: can u post the schema of both tables?

Comment: Will you tell relation column of both table

Comment: You can remove duplicate records using GROUP BY.

$query = "SELECT * FROM animals,birds GROUP BY field_name";

In above query field_name is which field you want to remove duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a cartesian product of all rows from the animals table with all rows from the birds table:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM animals,birds";
```

e.g. if you have 10 animals and 4 birds, you'll end up with 40 rows. You probably need a join:

```
select
  animals.*, birds.*
from
  animals inner join birds on birds.animal_id = animals.id
```

(the exact query depends on your database structure)